# A* Go application

Tags: beginner, go, coordinate-system, a-star

I've written a generic implementation of the A* algorithm as a first Go
program, since I had implemented that both in C and in Python before and Go
reminds me a bit of both. I'm looking for general commentary on bad practices,
specially concerning the following:

#### References

I don't think I've ever seen a struct being passed by value in C, though I can
think of some use cases. In Python, class instances are also "passed by
reference". Is that the way to go with Go? The lack of `const` makes it
tempting to pass something like `Pos` by value, though I guess in a function
like `astar` that might not be a good idea, as there can be a lot of iterations
and I guess the copy overhead would add up.

#### Slices

According to the docs I should think of them as "a pointer to a struct
containing a pointer to an array and a length", and the array has its length
embedded in the type. So should I even be using slices in here? Shouldn't I just
use an array, growing it as I go?

#### Ranges

I'm using them like a `for i in x` in Python, though I read a copy is created
in each iteration. Then again, with a large number of iterations isn't that a
bit costly? Perhaps I should be using a C-like `for i = 0; ...` loop instead?

General advice is also appreciated. I understand the code is a bit lengthy, I'm
not asking for any in-depth analysis though, just an overview.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// TODO separate things in packages

/* Error codes */
const (
  SUCCESS int = iota
  INTERNAL_ERROR
  NO_PATH
  TOO_FAR
  UNAVAILABLE
)

/* Define any object here */
type Obj struct {
  attr int8
}

/*
  Define the positional/distances type to be used in geo funcitons. This can be
  any numerical type, signed or unsigned, integer or real.
*/
type Coord int64;

/* Define any N-dimentional position struct here */
type Pos struct {
  y Coord
  x Coord
}

/* A grid represented by a hash table of the form { position : object } */
type Grid map[Pos]Obj

/* Don't A* if dst further than this, and stop iteration after this */
const MAX_PATHFINDING_STEPS Coord = 6000

/*
  Returns the positions in the shortest path between src and dst and an error
  code.

  grid    : { pos : obj }
  src      : source position
  dst      : destination position
  distance : returns the numeric distance between two positions
  nbors    : returns the available positions around a position
  avail    : tells if a position is available on the given grid
 */
func astar(grid Grid, src, dst *Pos, distance func(*Pos, *Pos)Coord, nbors func(Grid, *Pos, func(Grid, *Pos)bool)[]Pos, avail func(Grid, *Pos)bool) ([]Pos, int) {
  var path []Pos;
  if !avail(grid, dst) {
    return path, UNAVAILABLE
  }
  if distance(src, dst) > MAX_PATHFINDING_STEPS{
    return path, TOO_FAR
  }
  /* Hash table for O(1) search and deletion, the value is not used */
  visited := make(map[Pos]int8)
  to_be_visited := map[Pos]int8{ *src : 0 }
  came_from := make(map[Pos]Pos)
  d_src := map[Pos]Coord{ *src : 0 }
  d_dst := map[Pos]Coord{ *src : distance(src, dst) }
  for len(to_be_visited) > 0 && Coord(len(visited)) < MAX_PATHFINDING_STEPS {
    src = _argmin(d_dst)
    if distance(src, dst) == 0 {
      path = _reconstruct_path(came_from, *dst)
      return path, SUCCESS
    }
    delete(to_be_visited, *src)
    delete(d_dst, *src)
    visited[*src] = 0
    for _, nbor := range nbors(grid, src, avail) {
      _, hasbeenvisited := visited[nbor]
      if !hasbeenvisited {
        _, tobevisited := to_be_visited[nbor]
        temp_gscore := d_src[*src] + distance(&nbor, src)
        if !tobevisited || temp_gscore < d_src[nbor] {
          came_from[nbor] = *src
          d_src[nbor] = temp_gscore
          d_dst[nbor] = d_src[nbor] + distance(&nbor, src)
          to_be_visited[nbor] = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if len(to_be_visited) > 0 {
    return path, TOO_FAR
  } else {
    return path, NO_PATH
  }
}

/* For internal use, returns the &position with the least distance */
func _argmin(distances map[Pos]Coord) *Pos {
  var ans *Pos
  var min Coord = MAX_PATHFINDING_STEPS
  for spot, distance := range distances {
    if distance < min {
      min = distance
      ans = &spot
    }
  }
  return ans
}

/* For internal use */
func _reconstruct_path(came_from map[Pos]Pos, cur Pos) []Pos {
  ans := []Pos{cur}
  in := true
  for in {
    cur = came_from[cur]
    ans = append(ans, cur)
    _, in = came_from[cur]
  }
  return ans
}

/*
  The following functions provide the necessary arguments to do A* on a 2D grid
  (tiled map) with taxicab geometry (Manhattan distance)
*/

/*
  A position is available on the grid if it's coordinates are within the grid
  and there is no object ocupying them
*/
func available(grid Grid, pos *Pos)bool {
  // TODO for now this is hard coded
  if pos.x < 0 || pos.y < 0 || pos.x > 5 || pos.y > 2 {
    return false
  }
  _, ans := grid[*pos]
  return !ans
}

/* Exact copy of abs.go, except with Coord type */
func abs(x Coord) Coord {
  switch {
  case x < 0:
    return -x
  case x == 0:
    return 0 // return correctly abs(-0)
  }
  return x
}

/* Manhattan distance */
func mdistance(a, b *Pos) Coord {
  return abs(a.y - b.y) + abs(a.x - b.x)
}

/* The (at most 8) available positions around a spot in a grid */
func nbors(grid Grid, spot *Pos, avail func(Grid, *Pos)bool) []Pos {
  var ans []Pos;
  var i, j Coord
  // TODO assumes pos is signed and doesn't check for under/overflow
  for i = -1; i < 2; i++ {
    for j = -1; j < 2; j++ {
      nbor := Pos{spot.y + i, spot.x + j}
      if avail(grid, &nbor) {
        ans = append(ans, nbor)
      }
    }
  }
  return ans
}

func main() {
  /* Create the game map (ht pos : obj) */
  m := make(map[Pos]Obj)
  /*
    Map:

       012345
      0 #  # 0
      1# ### 1
      2#     2
       012345

    Src: 0, 0
    Dst: 0, 5
    Excpeted answer: {(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (1,5), (0,5)}
  */
  m[Pos{0,1}] = Obj{0}
  m[Pos{0,4}] = Obj{0}
  m[Pos{1,0}] = Obj{0}
  m[Pos{1,2}] = Obj{0}
  m[Pos{1,3}] = Obj{0}
  m[Pos{1,4}] = Obj{0}
  m[Pos{2,0}] = Obj{0}
  path, rc := astar(m, &Pos{0,0}, &Pos{0,5}, mdistance, nbors, available)
  fmt.Println(rc)
  fmt.Println(path)
}
```

Comment: "I don't think I've ever seen a struct being passed by value in C" But C _always_ passes by value ;)

Comment: Code will not compile - is the line `if !avail(grid, dst) {` supposed to be `if !available(grid, dst) {`?

Comment: @rolfl No, it's supposed to be as it is (using the function parameter `avail`) and it compiled fine here both with `go build` and `go run`. `go version go1.3.3 linux/386` from Debian Jessie repos (which provides Google's toolchain AFAIK).

Comment: So it is. Hmmm.. will bring the code down and actually run it. I missed the function parameter.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's fine to pass small immutable structs by value. It creates a new copy in memory, but it also creates clarity of purpose (you know that `func foo(p Pos)` doesn't and *cannot* modify `p`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Bug

Your code clearly states:

> ```
> Src: 0, 0
> Dst: 0, 5
> Excpeted answer: {(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (1,5), (0,5)}
> ```

But, when I run your code, I get:

```
[{0 5} {1 5} {2 4} {2 3} {2 2} {1 1} {0 0}]
```

Everything in reverse order. It is clear that your back-track to reverse the path taken is appending each point to the `ans` slice, instead of inserting each point at the beginning - and getting things in the right order.

Having said that, the append is probably the right solution, but a slice reversal afterwards would be better.

Your current back-track function is:

> ```
> /* For internal use */
> func _reconstruct_path(came_from map[Pos]Pos, cur Pos) []Pos {
>   ans := []Pos{cur}
>   in := true
>   for in {
>     cur = came_from[cur]
>     ans = append(ans, cur)
>     _, in = came_from[cur]
>   }
>   return ans
> }
> ```

I would instead make that:

```
/* For internal use */
func _reconstruct_path(came_from map[Pos]Pos, cur Pos) []Pos {
  ans := []Pos{cur}
  for cur, ok := came_from[cur]; ok; cur, ok = came_from[cur] {
    ans = append(ans, cur)
  }

  sz := len(ans)
  for i := sz / 2; i >= 0; i-- {
    ans[i], ans[sz - i - 1] = ans[sz - i - 1], ans[i]
  }

  return ans
}
```

Notice how I put the loop conditions in to the for-loop, which makes your out-of-loop `in` variable now in-scope for the loop. Also, I renamed it to `ok` to conform to common practice in go.

Then, I use the simple swap mechanism in go to reverse the `ans` slice.

#### Code Style

You have a number of convention-breaking habits in your code. For example, the following:

> ```
> /* For internal use */
> func _reconstruct_path(came_from map[Pos]Pos, cur Pos) []Pos {
> ```

Function names in go should not have any underscores in them, and should be `MixedCase` (for exported functions) or `mixedCase` for internal functions. This is true for variable names as well.

The underscore `_` or [`blank identifier`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank) has a special meaning in Go, and should be avoided in names.

That declaration should be:

```
func reconstructPath(cameFrom map[Pos]Pos, cur Pos) []Pos {
```

When running your code through the go lint-checker, it reported a number of problems in addition to the above (though the above code is what prompted me to run the lint checker):

> ```
> astar.go:10:3: don't use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase
> astar.go:11:3: don't use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase
> astar.go:12:3: don't use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase
> astar.go:16:1: comment on exported type Obj should be of the form "Obj ..." (with optional leading article)
> astar.go:21:1: comment on exported type Coord should be of the form "Coord ..." (with optional leading article)
> astar.go:27:1: comment on exported type Pos should be of the form "Pos ..." (with optional leading article)
> astar.go:33:1: comment on exported type Grid should be of the form "Grid ..." (with optional leading article)
> astar.go:36:1: comment on exported const MAX_PATHFINDING_STEPS should be of the form "MAX_PATHFINDING_STEPS ..."
> astar.go:37:7: don't use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase
> astar.go:60:3: don't use underscores in Go names; var to_be_visited should be toBeVisited
> astar.go:61:3: don't use underscores in Go names; var came_from should be cameFrom
> astar.go:62:3: don't use underscores in Go names; var d_src should be dSrc
> astar.go:63:3: don't use underscores in Go names; var d_dst should be dDst
> astar.go:77:9: don't use underscores in Go names; var temp_gscore should be tempGscore
> astar.go:89:10: if block ends with a return statement, so drop this else and outdent its block
> astar.go:97:11: should omit type Coord from declaration of var min; it will be inferred from the right-hand side
> astar.go:108:6: don't use underscores in Go names; func _reconstruct_path should be _reconstructPath
> astar.go:108:24: don't use underscores in Go names; func parameter came_from should be cameFrom
> ```

Running the `code fmt` on your code also made a difference - mostly in the spaces/tabs situation - go uses tabs.... for better or worse, always.

#### Naming

One item that had me confused for a bit, is this code:

> ```
> type Coord int64;
> ```

You define a "coordinate" as a single int64 - but, a coordinate is at least a 2 dimensional thing..... right? What you have there, is a distance. You call it a distance in some places, but in other places it makes the code funny... for example, here we have a function called `mdistance` which returns a `Coord`... ??? ...:

> ```
> /* Manhattan distance */
> func mdistance(a, b *Pos) Coord {
>   return abs(a.y - b.y) + abs(a.x - b.x)
> }
> ```

You have been overly enthusiastic in your type declaration for `Coord`, I think, and it should just be removed. Also, there's no real reason to make it an `int64`. A simple `int` will do fine - and you're probably on a 64-bit platform anyway.